# Page and post loop same template

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, content

I try to make template that has Page content in the main div but in the same page there is category base post loop whit title, day, content and read more link.

What i had now is like this

```
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    //Post thumbnails need this in functions.php: `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');`
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100));
    ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>



    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <!-- No posts found -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and to post the category loop is this.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=4" );
       if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
           while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
               $my_query->the_post();



                 echo '<div id="blogi_loop">';
                 echo '<h1>';
                the_title();
                echo '</h1>';
                the_date('m.d.Y');

               the_content();

               echo '</div>';              }
       }
       wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

How ever i see only one day format in the loop?
And how i see the read more link?

Answer (score 1):

Use the_excerpt() instead of the_content() - the_content() will only cut off if you do it manually.

Comment: Chirs thanks.
How about  the_date it show only in the firs loop?

Answer (score 1):

As Chris has mentioned you want to be using `the_excerpt()` rather than `the_content()`.

As for the date issue, see this [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date), in particular:

> SPECIAL NOTE: When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of `the_date()`). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag `the_time()` or `get_the_date()` (since 3.0) with a date-specific format string.
>   Use `<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>` to add the date set in the admin interface.

See [`the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) or [`get_the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) Codex pages.

Comment: Please mark answers as correct if they solve your problem. It means your question gets taken off the 'unanswered' pile, and makes it easier for others to recognize what worked for you.

Comment: @vj_andrei, I meant tick the answer :D. There is a tick to the left of each question, click the one that corresponds to answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this loop for category post.
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=4" );
   if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
       while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
           $my_query->the_post();



             echo '<div id="blogi_loop">';
             echo '<h1>';
            the_title();
            echo '</h1>';
            the_date('m.d.Y');

           the_excerpt();

           echo '</div>';              }
   }
   wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```